# 2 switches controlling two lights in garage.

Tags: wiring

I have two switches, (one inside the house, the other at the front of the garage). These control 2 lights in the ceiling of the garage.  I would like to install 4 new LED lights, and change the existing 2 lights into junction boxes. 3 wire runs in both switches. On one light base, there is 2 black, and 2 white.  On the other base, there is just a black and white.  Can I add a new 2 wire into this base and run to the new LED light? Marette off the black and the white wires?  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you can add those 4 LED light fixtures. Just connect parallel from your existing neutral switch wire and neutrals of the 2 light fixtures that you will be changing.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  Thank you for the quick reply, Joe!  I really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Great answer. +1